# Не зависимое ни от университета, ни от государства. Не раздельно?

Tags: орфография, предлоги, частица-не, прилагательные

Согласно правилу,

> к прилагательным относятся слова, образованные от непереходных глаголов:  независимые страны, независимое от внешних условий поведение, совершенно независимый характер, страны экономически независимы, эти страны независимее других. Но, согласно правилам написания не с прилагательными при наличии отрицательных местоимений и наречий, а также частиц далеко, отнюдь, не с прилагательными на -мый пишется раздельно: ни от чего не зависимый результат, отнюдь не зависимый взгляд на вещи.

Но в ответе справочной службы русского языка:

> Следует писать раздельно: не зависимое в финансовом отношении ни от университета, 
>   ни от государства.

Разве этот ответ правильный? Или здесь на раздельное написание НЕ влияет повторяющаяся частица ни (в составе союза ни… ни), усиливающая отрицание?

Comment: Интересная история. А если написать так: не зависимое в финансовом отношении  ни от чего: ни от университета, ни от государства. Что тогда выбирать будем, если правила разные?

Answer (score 2):

**При наличии усиления отрицания** (отрицательные местоимения и наречия,  частицы ***далеко не, отнюдь не***, однородные члены, связанные союзом НИ...НИ) **частица НЕ пишется раздельно** (за исключением тех случаев, когда слово без НЕ не употребляется:***никем непобедимый народ***).

**Это формальное требование для данной конструкции**, так как невозможна замена синонимом без НЕ: не зависимое   в финансовом отношении ни от университета, ни от государства.

**Примеры:**

Посол Резанов, уполномоченный заключить торговый союз с Японией, должен был также еще «приобрести остров Сахалин, **не зависимый ни от китайцев, ни от японцев»**. [А. П. Чехов. Остров Сахалин (1893-1895)]

Мы хотим иметь свой, **не зависимый ни от кого** театр. [Виктор Розов. Удивление перед жизнью (1960-2000)]

Надо сказать, что правило это **иногда нарушается в силу своей формальности**:

Они хотели выявить общечеловеческие биологические основания языков, **независимые ни от каких грамматических правил.**.. [Леонид Перловский. Сознание, язык и математика // «Звезда», 2003]

Comment: Я видел это правило-исключение (для отглагольных прилагательных на -мый) только в форме (вероятный первоисточник - Валгина/Розенталь): _при наличии в качестве пояснительных слов отрицательных **местоимений и наречий** (начинающихся с ни) или сочетаний далеко не, вовсе не, отнюдь не_. А в каком источнике оно распространено на все **усиления отрицания**?

Comment: В "корпусной" статистике с соотношением 4:3 побеждает раздельный вариант - за счёт двух источников после 2000 года (в дополнение к классикам). Сам я написал бы этот пример раздельно с причастием "_не зависящие_" - с прилагательным "независимые" (при любом его написании) не всегда естественно сочетаются зависимые слова.

Comment: А Лопатина не читаете? http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=79#pp79  2. В составе конструкций, усиливающих отрицание:в) с союзом ни... ни, напр.: "Ни хозяевам, ни гостям не известный мужчина; Не нужный ни мне ни тебе".  Это правило общее для всех прилагательных.

Comment: У Лопатина я не нашёл различения между _прилагательными_ и _причастиями_ на "-мый", приводимого Розенталем: _13. Различается написание частицы не с отглагольными прилагательными и причастиями на -мый. Прилагательные на -мый, как правило, образованы от непереходных глаголов (независимый, непромокаемый, несгораемый и т. п.)_. Именно к этому пункту отнесено исключение, которое я процитировал по тексту пособия с участием Валгиной, Розенталя и др.

Comment: Сейчас вижу, что по сравнению со "Справочником" Розенталя из формулировки там исключено "в частности" (перед _местоимениями и наречиями_) - возможно, при заимствовании это произошло случайно, но смысл изменился. http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77,7#pp77

Comment: А вывод какой?  Независимый - прилагательное (хотя и на МЫЙ),  НЕ пишется раздельно, что подтверждает ПАС. Или нет?  Да здесь и  справочника не нужно, просто подставьте синоним без НЕ, и тогда получим: "свободное в финансовом отношении ни от университета, ни от государства". Здесь дело в самой конструкции, она по своей структуре отрицательная. А вот по смыслу я не вижу здесь усиления признака, сравнить: нисколько не зависимый (наречие степени действительно усиливает признак).

Comment: Выводы такие. Лопатинский справочник не вдаётся в подробности, рассмотренные Розенталем. Прилагательное _независимый_ пишется слитно и при наличии зависимых слов (от кого). _...независимое в финансовом отношении от университета или от государства._ Присутствие же среди зависимых слов усилительных частиц **ни** формально требует _раздельного_ написания, характерного для _причастий_, но в данном конкретном случае без очевидной замены на **"не зависящие**" предложение оказывается _стилистически ущербным_

Comment: (возможно, именно поэтому Розенталь воздержался от примеров с "не зависимый ни от" и ограничился примером с "не устранимы ни...").

Comment: Трудно сказать, о чем именно думали классики, составляя для нас правила, но мы должны пользоваться этими правилами. А я так и не поняла, как Вы будете писать НЕ. Меня интересует Ваш коротенький ответ: слитно или раздельно.

Comment: Я просто не буду употреблять слово "зависимый" в конструкции "не-ни-ни", для этого есть причастие "зависящий" (раздельно). В этом предложении можно либо так, либо убрать "ни-ни" и написать "независимый" _слитно_.

Comment: Последний вопрос, а то нас выгоняют. Вы пишете тотальный диктант, и там встретилась такая конструкция.  Как Вы напишете НЕ?

Comment: Если нельзя будет изменить остальное, авторы "сапогов всмятку" получат от меня циркулярно-раздельное написание :) .

Comment: Ну, это не поможет. Здесь надо будет применить какое-нибудь физическое насилие.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ "службы" *правилен* по верно указанной в вашем вопросе причине: в конструкции "***не*** + отрицаемое суждение или слово + **ни** + обстоятельство 1 + **ни** + обстоятельство 2..." отрицательная частица **не** *не* может объединяться со следующим словом: она принадлежит схеме отрицания **не+ни+ни**. При исключении же из исходного выражения усилительных частиц **ни** написание было бы слитным, несмотря на наличие зависимых слов (http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77,7#pp77 см. п.13 о прилагательных на *-мый*):

> ... независимое в финансовом отношении от университета или от
>   государства.

В сочетании же с отрицающей конструкцией **не+ни+ни** естественнее употребить имеющее такой же смысл причастие **зависящий**:

> ... **не** *зависящее* в финансовом отношении **ни** от университета, **ни** от
>   государства.

Такая замена исключает возможные *на слух* разночтения: то ли употреблено самодостаточное прилагательное **независимый** (= не зависящий ни от кого - по Далю) то ли частица **не** участвует в сложном отрицании - от этой неясности возникает ощущение общей нескладности конструкции.